# SD Card and Lora module arduino uno

Tags: sd-card, wireless, rf

Background: When working on the 2 modules separately they were working perfectly.

Problem: In the code attached we tried integrating them but Lora wouldn't receive any data unless we commented out parts of the SDC function. Is there a fix to this?

This is where the problem occurs:

```
Serial.print("Data received: ");
 Serial.print(received); 

 if(received=="ANEMO"){
```

No matter how much we feed it with TRUE data from another Lora with these codes it simply shows blank and false.

Please Help this poor lamb. This for our school project. Hopefully, you can spare me some of your time. Thank you so much in advance.

for the CS pins:
Lora: pin 10,  SD: pin 5

other SPI pins follow the standard pins.

PS: In the code, we have commented out some of the lines within the SDC function as based on our observation:

```
myFile = SD.open("HG.txt", FILE_WRITE);
   myFile.close();
```

These 2 lines are the ones causing our Lora to not display the data it is receiving in the (String receive variable).

Thank you, good sir/ma'am, once again hopefully you can assist me.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>
#define RFM95_CS 10
#define RFM95_RST 9
#define RFM95_INT 2
#define RF95_FREQ 868.0
RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS, RFM95_INT);
unsigned long millisecs;
int cnt;
float valu;
String jh;
int code=1;
String received;


File myFile;

void setup(){
 Serial.begin(115200);
 if (!SD.begin(5)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    while (1);
  }
  else{
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
  }

  delay(100);

 pinMode(RFM95_RST, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
 while (!Serial);
 Serial.println("Arduino LoRa RX Test!");
 digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, LOW);
 delay(10);
 digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
 delay(10);
 while (!rf95.init()) {
 Serial.println("LoRa radio init failed");
 while (1);
 }
 Serial.println("LoRa radio init OK!");
 if (!rf95.setFrequency(RF95_FREQ)) {
 Serial.println("setFrequency failed");
 while (1);
 }
 Serial.print("Set Freq to: "); Serial.println(RF95_FREQ);
 rf95.setTxPower(23, false);
}

void lorA(){
  while(code==1){
if (rf95.waitAvailableTimeout(1000)){
 Serial.println("dayun ");
 uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
 uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
 if (rf95.recv(buf, &len)){
 cnt++;
 Serial.print("Data number: ");
 Serial.println(cnt);
 received=(char*)buf;
 Serial.print("Data received: ");
 Serial.print(received); 

 if(received=="ANEMO"){
 uint8_t data[] = "And hello back to you";
 rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
 rf95.waitPacketSent();
 Serial.println("Sent a reply");
 code=0;
 }
 }
 else{
 Serial.println("Receive failed");
 }
 }
 }
 }


void SDC(){
  while(code==0){
  Serial.println("SDC");
//  File dataFile = SD.open("HG.txt", FILE_WRITE);
//  String dataString="Hans";
//  if (dataFile) {
//  dataFile.println(dataString);
//  dataFile.close();
//    Serial.println("closed");
//    Serial.println(dataString);
    code=1;
//  }
//  else {
//    Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
//  }

  }
  }

void loop(){
  Serial.println("loop");
  lorA();
  Serial.println("mid");
  SDC();
}
```

Comment: what does `TRUE data` mean? .... you have a lot of print statements in your code but i see no mention of the printed data in your post ..

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry. Allow me to clarify, by TRUE what I meant was for the condition "if(received==" ANEMO")". If you notice on the complete code if the condition is satisfied the code is supposed to print "Sent a reply" but in our case, it didn't happen and we suspect the SD card code to be the one affecting it. We came to this idea as we tried commenting out some line of the SDC function(function for SD card) specifically the "myFile = SD.open("HG.txt", FILE_WRITE)". After we commented it out the Lora started working properly again such that when it receives ANEMO in the serial it displays Sent.

Comment: most SD modules disturb the SPI bus and other SPI devices not work with them

Comment: Damn sir/ma'am... That's going to be a huge problem. Aren't there any workarounds for the problem? Anyways thank you, sir/ma'am.

Answer (score 1):

all of your problem can be solved through a simple trick ... Just follow it...

1. Use Sdfat library insted of SD
2. just follow SPI datasheet..

follow below code ... it works with LORA AND SD both together

```
... 

#include <SdFat.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RHReliableDatagram.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>

SdFat sd;
SdFile myFile;

#define chipSelect 4

#define RFM95_CS 10 //
#define RFM95_RST 9
#define RFM95_INT 2

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS,RFM95_INT);
//RH_RF95 driver(5, 2); // Rocket Scream Mini Ultra Pro with the RFM95W

// Class to manage message delivery and receipt, using the driver declared above
RHReliableDatagram manager(rf95, 2);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {}  // wait for Leonardo

  delay(100);

  // Initialize SdFat or print a detailed error message and halt
  // Use half speed like the native library.
  // change to SPI_FULL_SPEED for more performance.
  pinMode(RFM95_CS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_CS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);

  if (!sd.begin(chipSelect, SPI_HALF_SPEED)) sd.initErrorHalt();

/*

/*
 * //Open file and write  ...
 * 
  // open the file for write at end like the Native SD library
  if (!myFile.open("mrinmoy.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_AT_END)) {
    sd.errorHalt("opening test.txt for write failed");
  }


  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
  myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");


  // close the file:
  myFile.close();
  Serial.println("done.");
  */

  /*
  // open the file for reading....

  if (!myFile.open("mrinmoy.txt", O_READ)) 
  {
    sd.errorHalt("opening test.txt for read failed");
  }

  Serial.println("mrinmoy.txt:");


  // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
  int data;

  while ((data = myFile.read()) >= 0) Serial.write(data);
  // close the file:
  myFile.close();
  */

  // manual reset
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);

  digitalWrite(RFM95_CS, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);

  while (!manager.init()) {
    Serial.println("LoRa radio init failed");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("LoRa radio init OK!");

 // digitalWrite(RFM95_CS, LOW);

}

void loop()
{
   uint8_t data[] = " Hi.. This is node 1.";
 //   unsigned char sd_data[50];
// Dont put this on the stack:
 // uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
   uint8_t buf[50];
  // nothing happens after setup

  //LoRa.setPins( LoRa_CS, LoRa_RST, DI0 );
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);    //  deselet SD Card SPI
  digitalWrite(RFM95_CS, LOW);    //  SELECT (low) LoRa SPI 
  SPI.begin();

  // Send a message to manager_client
  if (manager.sendtoWait((uint8_t*)data,sizeof(data),1))
  {
    Serial.print("successfully sent to: ");
    Serial.println(1);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("send failed");
  }

  // receiver ....

   // Now wait for a reply from the server
   uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
   uint8_t from;

   if (manager.recvfromAckTimeout(buf, &len, 2000, &from))
    {
      Serial.print("Got Response From : 0x");
      Serial.print(from, HEX);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
    }
    else
    {

    } 
 //   digitalWrite(4, LOW);
   SPI.end();

   digitalWrite(4, LOW);    //  deselet SD Card SPI
   digitalWrite(RFM95_CS,HIGH);    //  SELECT (low) LoRa SPI 
   SPI.begin();


 if (!myFile.open("mrinmoy.txt", O_READ)) 
  {
    sd.errorHalt("opening test.txt for read failed");
  }

  Serial.println("mrinmoy.txt:");
  char ch;
  String str;
  int i=0;
  uint8_t sd_data[50];

  while (myFile.available()>0) 
  {
    ch= myFile.read(); 
    str+=ch;
  }

  String str2=str;
  Serial.println(str2);
  Serial.println(str2.length());


  myFile.close();
  SPI.end();


  delay(500);
}
```

use this trick ... your system will work perfectly ...